# Для каких целей используется NodeJs?

Tags: веб-программирование, node.js, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Если я правильно понял Wiki, то он дает возможность использовать JavaScript на стороне сервера.
Однако, в виду своего малого опыта я не могу представить задачи, которые можно было решать только лишь его средствами.
Подскажите, под какие задачи обычно используется NodeJs или это какая-то узконаправленная штука?
Используют ли его в ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ilyaigpetrov/f6df3e6f825ae1b5c7e2

Comment: @andreycha вы привели очень странное сравнение. Там же половина фактов выдуманы...

Comment: Задач, решаемых только его средствами, и нет. Просто народу вдруг захотелось запхнуть js на сервера, вот и пихают)

Answer (score 5):

Node.js используют под совершенно разные задачи. Например:

- как backend для различных сетевых сервисов (не только веб):

  - Express;
  - Koa;
  - Meteor;
- как платформу для IoT (Internet of Things):

  - Cylon;
  - Robot.js;
- как платформу для написания настольных приложений:

  - Atom;
- как платформу для написания системных инструментов, в том числе:

  - менеджеров пакетов: npm, bower, jspm;
  - систем сборки проекта: gulp, grunt;
  - систем упаковки ресурсов: browserify, webpack;
  - PostCSS;
  - babel (транслятора из современного Javascript в более старые версии);
  - tsc (компилятора Typescript);

В ASP.NET MVC его можно использовать, например для работы с CSS (PostCSS) или для перекомпиляции JS (Babel).

Более того, старая версия node.js поставляется вместе с Visual Studio 2015 - и такие вещи как tsc в некоторых шаблонах проектов настроены из коробки.

Answer (score 0):

Цитата из книги Брауна "Web разработка с использованием Node.js и Express":
"Случалось ли вам заходить на сайт, видеть строку запроса, заканчивающуюся ***.asp, и думать - как же этот сайт устарел!"

Вы бы лучше спросили, чего Node.js не может.
Javascript - наверное, самый ушлый язык: ворует все лучшие идеи из всех языков и платформ (что особенно трогательно - много из Lisp, самый трогательный си-образный наследник великого Lisp). Короче, это язык (и платформа) для людей, больше всего ценящих свободу.

Answer (score 0):

Использую его в Back-End. Если про конкретику, то он отлично подходит для IM-сервера, сервера очереди сообщений, а также любых вещей, связанных с Back-End обработкой данных.

Answer (score -1):

Например, я делал реалтайм игру под Вконтакте. Node.js использовал для front-end(балансировщик между серверами) и back-end.

Node.js способен даже заменить ungix для отдачи статики, хотя это полемика на форумах развела не слабые рассуждения.

Comment: "Node.js способен даже заменить nginx" в теории способен, но на практике это слабо реализуемо) разработчики этого сервера далеко ушли вперед по сравнению с написанием подобных проектов "с нуля".